# Why is my Render Image output correct but my Render Animation output is incorrect?

Tags: rendering

I made a test scene to develop a workflow for dividing up a Cycles animation into separate render layers, rendering them out and recombining them.

I noticed as I was putting everything back together that the frames from the render layers with masking, that were rendered with Render Animation (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>) have all kinds of inaccuracies where the masking is wrong, but when I re-render the messed up frame with Render Image (<kbd>F12</kbd>) the bad frame is suddenly rendered correctly. What is even more perplexing is that the mistakes are not consistent. When I re-render with Render Animation (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>), the errors can appear on different frames and other previously inaccurate frames can get fixed.

I am getting these errors when I Load Factory Settings and then open the scene.

Hopefully someone has some idea why this is occurring and how to fix it.

Below is an example of the Torus in the scene that is on its own render layer. The Torus render layer is configured so that the Cone render layer is enabled in the Render Layers>Mask section. You can clearly see that the Torus render layer output, when rendered from Render Animation, is not correct like the output from Render Image.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6647893/Forum_Help/Render_Layer_Animation_Test2.zip

[image: Open GL Render of Frame 06]

Open GL Render of Frame 06
[image: Frame 06 rendered with Render Animation]

Frame 06 rendered incorrectly with Render Animation
[image: Frame 06 rendered with Render Image]

Frame 06 rendered correctly with Render Image

Comment: What version of blender are you using? I just tried it with 2.75 and could not replicate the error you're describing.

Comment: Also, why are you excluding all other layers for each render layer? You won't get any lighting/shading interaction between the objects at all that way.

Comment: Third question, can you launch Blender from the terminal and see if any errors are shown in the terminal for any of the incorrect frames?

Comment: I am using Blender 2.76. According to this: http://www.blenderguru.com/articles/how-to-render-a-complex-scene-without-crashing/ Exclude boxes are for "specifically telling Blender what to exclude from the memory calculation". Before I read that I wasn't using them at all. I don't know how to launch Blender from a terminal but I can research that.

Comment: Keep in mind, like I reported, the problem could be on other frames and Frame 06 could be fine when you render it.

Comment: I tried it on a completely different PC and got the same errors. Torus Frame 0030 for example, is totally wrong when using Render Animation, but fine with Render Image.

Comment: Hmm, I've tested twice with 2.75 and 2.76 and enabled all 4 render layers, and set up alpha over nodes in the compositor to combine everything. I've done 30 frame animation renders 4 times now and they all look error free.

Comment: gpu or cpu render?

Comment: I'm getting the same error http://i.stack.imgur.com/2dGmO.gif just rendering with Ctrl F12 or plain F12 does look different... rendering on GPU

Comment: Yep, I am seeing the same thing as cegaton. I am rendering on GPU since that is what I will be doing on my actual render. Also, I was rendering out each render layer into a separate directory to simulate multiple computers doing the job.